# How to hide a main page div when clicking on another tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

I am using the w3schools HOW TO - tabs to make tabs for my website. The problem is, every time i click on tab other than 'Home', the 'Home' div still appears, and the other tab's content also appears under it. How do I hide the home page div when clicking on other tabs so I just see the content of mentioned tab?

Here is my nav HTML code and JavaScript I'm using:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" >
     function openTab(evt, tabName) {
     // Declare all variables
     var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

     // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
     tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
     for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
         tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
     }

     // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
     tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
     for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
         tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
     }

     // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
     document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
     evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   
  </script>
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ben and Lukes</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#intro" class="tablinks active" onclick="openTab(event, 'intro')">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#About" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'About')">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Products" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Products')">Products</a></li> 
          <li><a href="#Contact" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Contact')">Contact Us</a></li> 
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify your JS

JS

```
openTab("Home")

function openTab(tabName) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
}
```

Then HTML should look something like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<ul class="w3-navbar w3-black">
    <li><a href="#" onclick="openTab('Home')">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="openTab('AboutUs')">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="openTab('Products')">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="openTab('ContactUs')">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="Home" class="w3-container tab">
    <h2>Home</h2>
    <p>Your Content Here</p>
</div>

<div id="AboutUs" class="w3-container tab">
    <h2>About Us</h2>
    <p>Your Content Here</p> 
</div>

<div id="Products" class="w3-container tab">
    <h2>Products</h2>
    <p>Your Content Here</p>
</div>

<div id="ContactUs" class="w3-container tab">
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    <p>Your Content Here</p>
</div>
```

Check out the [Live CODEPEN here](http://codepen.io/illdapt/pen/jrrdjW)

Comment: I should clarify, when I launch the website I want the Home page to appear. The home page consists of a simple div with a container/background-image etc and an image. Subsequently, when clicking a tab e.g. "About Us", I want the 'About Us' tab content to appear and the 'Home' page content to dissapear.

Comment: Did you check out the pen? Is that not what you mean?

Comment: My apologies, I just did and that is exactly what I'm looking for, I'll try modelling it again using your code. I might have to completely dump my code and re-make the framework. I'll let you know how it goes :)

Comment: It works great Illdapt, however upon loading the website every single div is visible, and everything doesn't become hidden until I click on a tab, then the code kicks in. Is there some kind of onLoad function that automatically clicks the 'Home' tab upon page load? Thank you very much :)

Comment: Yes. Place the script within
    `$( document ).ready(function() {
        YOUR CODE HERE
    });`

Note this uses JQUERY, You must add the following before your other `<script>` on the HTML:

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"  integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: It all worked out in the end I had to fiddle around with some code that was causing problems. Cannot thank you enough champion :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using some jQuery:

```
$(".otherTab").click(function(){
      $('.homeTab').hide();
      $('.otherTab').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to use jquery you could use an [ng-switch directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch). you would then have some piece of state on the controller like displayTab = 0 by default. clicking on a tab would then change that piece of state and then the ng-switch would display the correct tab